# How to implement <optgroup> in laravel blade templeting engine

Tags: php, laravel-4, template-engine, laravel-blade

Let I have `HTML` select box like

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Fruits">
     <option>Orange</option>
     <option>Apple</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Food">
     <option>Chicket</option>
     <option>Beef</option>
    </optgroup> 
</select>
```

Now How can I implement this select box in `laravel` `blade` template engine

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this;

```
{{ Form::select('list', array(
    'Fruits' => array('Orange', 'Apple'),
    'Food' => array('Chicken', 'Beef'),
))}}
```

The output should be what your looking for.

To assign the values of the select options add keys to the array like `'<your_value>' => 'Orange'`.